# TypeError: targetItem.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am trying to make this onChange function dynamic but running into TypeError. Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

This way works as expected:

```
onChange = e => {
        // current array of workShifts
        const workShifts = this.state.workShifts;
        let index;
        // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
        if (e.target.checked) {
            // add the numerical value of the checkbox to workShifts array
            workShifts.push(e.target.value);
        } else {
            // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
            index = workShifts.indexOf(e.target.value);
            workShifts.splice(index, 1);
        }
        // update the state with the new array of workShifts
        this.setState({ workShifts: workShifts });

        console.log('State:', this.state);
    };
```

New function that generates TypeError:

```
onChange = e => {
        // current array in state
        const dataGroup = e.target.getAttribute('data-group');
        const targetItem = 'this.state.' + dataGroup;
        let index;
        // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
        if (e.target.checked) {
            // add the value of the checkbox to array 
            targetItem.push(e.target.value);
        } else {
            // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
            index = targetItem.indexOf(e.target.value);
            targetItem.splice(index, 1);
        }
        // update the state with the new array
        this.setState({ [dataGroup]: targetItem });

        console.log('State:', this.state);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `push` method from `string`.
Try instead of `const targetItem = 'this.state.' + dataGroup;` 
use `const targetItem =  this.state[dataGroup];`